# What Star Wars Race/Species is this?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Has anyone an idea what race this character is?

[image: A female humanoid dressed in all black robes holding a red lightsaber in either hand. She has a white face with 2 red stripes on either cheek and 3 on her forehead. She has black hair in a ponytail]

Comment: Given the various technologies and (force) magic in Star Wars, this character could just be human with altered eyes.

Comment: *"female Sith concept"* - Not much help there since she's clearly not an actual Sith (species-wise).

Answer (score 2):

This is the creation of digital artist Serge Birault. You can find the original version of the artwork on their Art Station profile [here](https://app.artstation.com/artwork/Z3O5G) (this still loads initially but then redirects to a 404 for me currently). This is what the page looks like, note the title *"We have cookies"* and the caption *"Quick female Sith concept for fun"*:

[image: Concept art on the left with the info panel on the right]

The second iteration, the one in question, can be found [here](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/GZ24N). Note it also has the title *"We have cookies #2"*.

Serge also posted this on their Twitter page [here](https://twitter.com/birault_serge/status/1301500928659464192) with the caption *"SW fan arts."* showing both version of the art.

It's also worth noting though that Serge is Lead Concept Artist at Virtuos, a company that has had involvement working with Star Wars. For example, they [worked on *Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order*](https://www.virtuosgames.com/news/game/virtuos-supported-respawn-entertainment-on-gameplay-level-design-and-art-for-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order/). It's unlikely this was work created for Fallen Order given the time Serge posted it on their profile but it could have inspired future work. Having played Fallen Order this does strike me as somewhat similar, costume-wise not species/race, to the [Second Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Sister) and note she also has a dual lightsaber.

[image: Profile of the Second Sister with her helmet on and her dualsaber extended stood in the dark rain] [image: Close up of the Second Sister's human looking face with her helmet off]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

So, whilst not a direct inspiration for the character I can see some similarities between the two.

However, to answer your question it would appear that this is just fan art and so the female character has no known race/species and isn't canonical.